# Facebook Share dialog given url must match the Website URL or Canvas URL error

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am creating a simple share this page on facebook dialog, however I am getting the error 'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.'

The domain I am working from is for this example 'app.mydomain.co.uk'

Within the FB app settings my site url is 'http://www.app.mydomain.co.uk'

Within the FB app settings my app domain is 'app.mydomain.co.uk'

Any help resolving this would be great.